# Unprivileged LXC - Cannot set tx queue length

Tags: openvpn, proxmox, lxc

I've installed and configured OpenVPN server on unprivileged LXC.

Everything works fine except for one problem/warning:

```
Cannot set tx queue length on tun0: Operation not permitted (errno=1)
```

My tun0 interface:

```
12: tun0: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN group default qlen 500
link/none
inet 10.8.0.1/24 scope global tun0
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 fe80::6f17:9a60:8091:1484/64 scope link stable-privacy
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Unfortunately, I have no idea how to solve this. Any idea?